How can I create a dynamic variable with respect to my table row? Here I am providing a small React code snippet
// dianamic variable for accepting table values

const [revChange, setRevChange] = useState({});

const rcTableRows = 5; // from user
const no_rows = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= rcTableRows; i++) {
  let key = `r${i}`;
  revChange[key] = {
    revision: "",
    date: "",
    reason: "",
    remarks: "",
  };
  no_rows.push(`r${i}`);
}

<tbody>
  {no_rows.map((res, index) => (
    <tr>
      <td class="border border-slate-200 ...">{index + 1}</td>

      <td className="border border-slate-200">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="rev"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setRevChange((prevData) => ({
              ...prevData,
              [res]: {
                ...prevData[res],
                [name]: value, // Update the specific field (e.g., revision)
              },
            }));
          }}
          name="revision" // Optional: Use 'name' attribute for field identification
        />
      </td>

      <td class="border border-slate-200 ...">Date</td>
      <td class="border border-slate-200 ...">Reason for changes</td>
      <td class="border border-slate-200 ...">Remarks</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>

How can I create a dynamic variable with respect to my table row? Here I am providing a small React code snippet. I need to know how I can implement that logic in my given code.
I can't accept data from my input field to the given dynamic variable. Is there any solution?

What's your actual problem here? At a quick glance, it looks like your code would be doing what I might expect it to..?
